# Remix: Simple solidity function errored: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

I have a problem with simple solidity code in Remix.
Even I give 10 ETH(testnet) to the contract C but it doesn't work.
Error is:

> transact to C.makeContract errored: gas required exceeds allowance or
>   always failing transaction

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract A{
    uint public a;
    function setA(uint _a){
        a = _a;
    }
    function getData() constant returns (uint){
        return a;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function getData() constant returns (uint) {
        return a * 10;
    }
}

contract C {
    A[] internal c;
    function () payable {}
    function makeContract() returns (uint, uint){ //I have no idea why     this function occurs error
        c.length = 2;
        A a = new A();
        a.setA(1);
        c[0] = a;
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(1);
        c[1] = b;
        return (c[0].getData(), c[1].getData());
    }
}
```

Here is my solidity code. HELP ME PLZ!!

Comment: Ran it on remix just as you post it, and it works

Comment: Code seems to be running fine using Remix. I even tried the various Run settings such as "Javascript VM", "Injected Web3" and "Web3 provider" . Works fine! Are you facing this error every time you run the code, or occasionally only?  Are you using any tools in conjunction with Remix (Metamask?, Ganache?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your are calling `C.makeContract` with ether but your function is not payable.

Send your transaction without ether and it should be fine. You need to understand the difference between `value` and `Gas limit`.